# Condition on $k$ if $|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=k$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can we prove that 
$$|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=k$$

will represent a circle  if $|z_1-z_2|^2 \leq 2k$

Please give me some hints to initiate this question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint equation is of the form $x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{k})^2$ so $2k$ is the diameter of the circle if $|z_1-z_2|>2k$ then the points are apart by  a distance greater than the diameter. And we know diameter is the longest chord so $|z_1-z_2|\leq 2k$ is a necessary condition for it to be a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Making a translation and/or a rotation if necessary, we can assume $\;a:=z_1,\,b:=z_2\in\Bbb R^\;$ (this means: to "align" the line through $\;z_1,\,z_2\;$ with the real axis by means of translation/rotation), so putting $\;z=x+iy\;$ we get

$$(x-a)^2+y^2+(x-b)^2+y^2=k\iff 2x^2+2y^2-2(a+b)x=k-(a^2+b^2)\iff$$

$$\iff\left(x-\frac{a+b}2\right)^2+y^2=\frac{k-(a^2+b^2)}2+\frac{(a+b)^2}4$$

and thus the above represents a circle (with center at $\;\left(\frac{a+b}2,\,0\right)\;$) iff the rightside is non-negative, iff

$$2(a^2+b^2)-2k\le a^2+2ab+b^2\iff (a-b)^2\le2k$$